# Aggregating within CASE

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables, one storing enquiries (e_key) and one storing events attached to that enquiry. These Events have lengths of time assigned to them. I want to add up the total time attached to an enquiry and then use a CASE to assign it to one of three size categories, which I am using as an x axis on a bar chart.

I am using this to set up a Dimension field on the charting software we integrate with as my select:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Light Touch' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 THEN 'b. Medium Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' ELSE 'Unspecified' END
```

and I get 'an aggregate function is not valid in the context in which it was invoked'. This is because when the select is copied into the GROUP BY it doesn't like the use of SUM().

This is the full SQL the chart is generating (e_key count on y axis, size band on x axis):

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(Enquiry.E_KEY)) AS S1, CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 THEN 'b. Medium Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' ELSE 'Unspecified' END AS D1
FROM 
   DB2ADMIN.F_ENQUIRY Enquiry
   LEFT JOIN DB2ADMIN.F_EVENTS Events ON Enquiry.E_KEY = Events.EVENT_KEY
    JOIN DB2ADMIN.F_PRIORITY EnquiryType ON Enquiry.E_PRIORITY_LINK = EnquiryType.PRIORITY_NO
WHERE 
   (EnquiryType.PRIORITY_NAME =  'Enquiry'  ) 
AND   (Enquiry.e_job_type_link=0)
AND   (Events.EVENT_TYPE=2)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 THEN 'b. Medium Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' ELSE 'Unspecified' END
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 THEN 'b. Medium Intensity' WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' ELSE 'Unspecified' END
```

I cannot separate the SELECT from the GROUP BY section using the interface. Any ideas on different ways to achieve this? If I set the Type to Measure rather than Dimension it works as expected but then I cannot use it on an x axis. If I set up the same field excluding SUM() around EVENT_TIME_SPENT it allows me to set Type to Dimension and still work.

Comment: Use the first query to create a view.

Comment: Another option is make the query with the Summing a subquery and do the CASE checks in the outer query.

Comment: I'm not very good at this so if you could show me the structure of either of these suggestions I'll have a go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregates in the GROUP BY.

As it is, you are only wanting one row back right?

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(E_KEY)) AS S1
,      CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' 
           WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 
            THEN 'b. Medium Intensity'
           WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' 
           ELSE 'Unspecified' END AS D1
FROM 
   TABLE(VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)) AS Events (E_KEY, EVENT_TIME_SPENT)
```

which returns

```
 S1     D1
 --     -----------------
  2     c. High Intensity
```

if you want to group by something, then e.g. this works

```
SELECT E_KEY AS S1
,      CASE WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' 
           WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 1 AND SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) < 3 
            THEN 'b. Medium Intensity'
           WHEN SUM(Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT) >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' 
           ELSE 'Unspecified' END AS D1
FROM 
   TABLE(VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)) AS Events (E_KEY, EVENT_TIME_SPENT)
GROUP BY
    E_KEY


 S1     D1
 --     -------------------
  1     c. High Intensity
  2     b. Medium Intensity
```

or if you don't want to SUM() you EVENT_TIME_SPENT by anything, you might be after this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E_KEY) AS S1
,      CASE WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' 
           WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT >= 1 AND Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT < 3 
            THEN 'b. Medium Intensity'
           WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' 
           ELSE 'Unspecified' END AS D1
FROM 
   TABLE(VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,0),(1,4)) AS Events (E_KEY, EVENT_TIME_SPENT)
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT < 1 THEN 'a. Low Intensity' 
           WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT >= 1 AND Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT < 3 
            THEN 'b. Medium Intensity'
           WHEN Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT >= 3 THEN 'c. High Intensity' 
           ELSE 'Unspecified' END

 S1 D1
 -- -------------------
  1 a. Low Intensity   
  2 b. Medium Intensity
  1 c. High Intensity
```

Comment: As D1 is the x axis I need it to return only three rows, one for each level of intensity. If I'm understanding you correctly grouping by e_key will still give me one row per enquiry.

Comment: If you need to aggregate  Events.EVENT_TIME_SPENT  at some level, then you would need a sub-select. If you don't want to aggregate it, then use by last suggestion added above

Comment: It's the sub select within a case that I can't figure out how to format.